# Connect Direct Multiple files, one Node.

Tags: file, connection, transmission

I'm working on a project that requires sending multiple files to the same node. The files are available for sending at the same time and I created a simple C.D shell script to send the files. I looped the call to this script to send all the files (about 20) at the same time. 
In my script I'm intending to delete the files within the loop and after the CD script is called. However,.. some one at work , a colleague, told me that the files may not be sent on the spot but rather put in a queue for transmission at a later stage if the C.D node is busy and hence deleting the files would cause errors.

Can someone advise if this is the case? Are the files not fiscally copied even if put in a queue?
I find it weird that the CD script would complete with a successful return code and give me the process number and I still cannot delete the file?

Thanks, 
Sergio

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if statement for each file, if the exit code for the file is 0, only the file is deleted and CD moves to the next step for copying the next file.

```
if (step01=0) then
   run task (Do something)
   sysopts="rm filename"
```